# Accessing to session objects from facelets

Tags: session, jsf, facelets

we are working on a customer platform project and we have some doubts about the session objects and the best way to access them.

In order, it may be:

1. Login from client
2. SessionScopped bean gets fired with the template render.
3. Diferent pages (facelets) with ViewScoped or RequestScoped bean to navigate to sections.

We are injecting the sessionscoped bean to the rest of the beans when needed, so we have the same properties everywhere.

The doubt is, in the diferent facelets of sections, how we should access to the session objects? i mean

```
#{requestscopedbean.sessionscopedbean.object}
```

or should be directly calling to the session bean like:

```
#{sessionscopedbean.object}
```

We use PrimeFaces 6.2, I guess it is not the point. Just in case. And we are running all this on a javaee-5 compatible server

Comment: You should use @Named on your session scoped bean and access it directly with `#{sessionScopedBean.object}` no need to ask for it through the requestBean.

Comment: @Melloware: `@Named` in java-ee5?

Comment: We tried to use CDI but isnt working. So we are using @ManagedBean until we update the javaee version.

Comment: @Kukeltje he never said he was using EE5 just PF 6.2?

Comment: @Melloware: There was a (too broad) javaee-5 tag on the question when you commented. I removed that at a later time but forgot to add it in the text that OP is using javaee-5

Comment: Woops yeah i never even saw it!